# Receive MapMessage in activemq

Tags: java, activemq-classic

Using the activeMq for messages transmission, I came across the MapMessage as described here:

[MapMessage  Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/jms/MapMessage.html).

It enables the construction of a message in a map structure.

My question is- how to receive a MapMessage out of the queue (and not as a regular TestMessage)?

Senging a message is described in different tutorials (such as http://www.novell.com/documentation/extend52/Docs/help/MP/jms/tutorial/queueRequestor-1.htm) but I didn't came across examples about the extraction of a message.

Answer (score 0):

[QueueRequestor#request](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/jms/QueueRequestor.html#request%28javax.jms.Message%29) will return you the Message which in your case will be of type of MapMessage.

Just do this:

```
MapMessage result = (MapMessage)requestor.request(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

After checking the issue more thoroughly, I figured that it was my misunderstanding. 
Receiving MapMessage is possible even when using regular MessageConsumer:

```
public MapMessage recieveMassage(){
    MapMessage m = null;
    try {
        Message message = consumer.receive();
        if (message instanceof MapMessage) {
            m = (MapMessage) message;
            logger.log(Level.FINEST, "message received:\n" + m.toString()+"\n");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Received: " + message);
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error message not of MapMessage type: "+ message);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error receiving a message: " + e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return m;
}
```

The issue is that the message itself I sent using the activeMq console. Apparently, just writing the body of the message as a map (e.g.: {a1 = c1, a2 = c2 ...}) is not sufficient and the type is interpenetrated as a regular TextMessage.